# Are the roads in South Island in New Zealand very curvy?

Tags: driving, new-zealand

My husband and I are flying to Queenstown in January 2019 (Summer). We will be hiring a car and driving to Milford Sound, Te Anau, Roys Peak, and Mount Cook. I do have a problem with motion sickness especially on mountainous area if the roads get too curvy. I am very excited to go there but a bit anxious thinking about the motion sickness. I usually throw up if it gets too much. I just was curious to know if it will be really bad all the way or just patches of curvy road(which I can handle most of the time).

Any Information/advise will be useful to me so I can be prepared or make changes to our trip since we still have time to change bookings.

Comment: Because one person's "curvy" is another person's "delightful," and the OP's tolerance for motion sickness hard to quantify, I reluctantly (I use "reluctantly" because we've traveled delightfully thrice in NZ in will do so a fourth time in early 2019) conclude this question is opinion-based, and unsuitable for SE.

Comment: Expect the roads from Queenstown to Milford Sound to be winding, narrow in places, and sometimes difficult for the uninitiated. This applies to many of the roads around the Southern Alps - it's a mountain region, after all. Conversely, some of the more major roads can be relatively straight and flat. Whether any of this is 'really bad' is entirely subjective.

Comment: Great thanks, that's probably good information for me. It was hard to understand the roads on Google maps. I kind of get the vibe. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends a lot of your frame of reference. The road to Milford Sound is a mountain road going over a fairly high pass, so it is windy by nature. This being said, it's a well build two lane road and fairly easy to maneuver. It's a lot better than some mountain roads in Tuscany and a lot worse than driving through Texas.

My wife is prone to car sickness and she did not had any problems on that stretch. She is more susceptible to abrupt starting and stopping and "yanking", i.e very quick change of direction. That's less of issue on the Milford Sound road.

If you can give examples of roads that you have trouble with, we may be able to advise better.

Comment: Oh that's sort of my problem too. I have not had any issues going up and down mountains in  say Gold Coast Tamborine areas where the two lane roads are well built and slow curves around the mountain.But I had trouble near a very short pass in Robertson, towards Kiama which had very sharp turns at 45 angles on mountains roads. I could not absolutely go up himalayas towards Nainital as the roads were very narrow and turning too quickly. But it seems your wife and I have similar sort of issues. Many thanks